# Trying to create a folder with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a folder with Ruby move-to-go cmd, but im not able to do it. Not quite sure what the problem is. I am using "Start Command Prompt With Ruby", I have installed ruby and move-to-go. The cmd that im trying to do is

```
 move-to-go new Folder excel
```

Im getting 8 recent calls message: `"new", "run", "invoke_command", "dispatch", "start", "<top (required>", "load", "<main>"`

the error msg is:

```
uninitialized constant MoveToGoCommandLine::OpenSSL (NameError)
Did you mean? Open3
```

all help is appriciated!

Comment: Try adding the code you're actually working on, what you've added is still not enough to think in an answer to your problem.

Comment: @SebastianPalma im not working on any code, im just trying to create a folder. This is the only thing that I have done

Comment: @LillyAndersen What code is generating that error message?

Comment: @jhpratt when I try running this cmd "move-to-go new Folder excel" after installing "gem install move-to-go"

Answer (score 0):

I've just looked at MoveToGo's source code, and it looks like a bug in their executable. Especially that they haven't required (`require 'openssl'`) openssl in `bin/move-to-go`.

If I were you, I'd go and make an issue on their GitHub issue tracker [here](https://github.com/Lundalogik/move-to-go/issues).

Its a basic scope issue when libraries aren't explicitly required..

Comment: Thanks! Well, would it be solved by trying another version? Right now im running the latest one, 2.5 I think

Comment: Try the 5.0.7 version, that is the release before that code was added

Comment: Its not a problem with ruby, its a problem with move-to-go

Comment: Also note that there is a name change between then and now, it used to be fruit_to_lime, and upon further inspection, the command `new` is not implemented in that version, so I don't believe you're going to get anywhere.